# Adding multiple middleware to Restify conditionalHandler

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, routes, restify

Looking to use the Restify conditionalHandler plugin, and I have multiple middleware in certain routes.

Looking to convert this:

```
server.put('/forceUpdate', middleware.requiresLogin, versionController.update);
```

into something like this

```
server.put('/addVersion', restify.plugins.conditionalHandler([
    {version: '1.1.3', handler: middleware.requiresLogin, versionController.update},
    {version: '2.0.1', handler: middleware.requiresLogin, versionController.update}
]));
```

I can't chain the middleware in the handler, is there a best practice for this?

Does handler accept an array?

My other thought adding more middleware as conditionalHandlers, but that seems excessive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an array of middleware functions according to the [documentation](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#conditionalhandler). So your code will look like this:

```
server.put('/addVersion', restify.plugins.conditionalHandler([
  {version: '1.1.3', handler: [middleware.requiresLogin, versionController.update]},
  {version: '2.0.1', handler: [middleware.requiresLogin, versionController.update]}
]));
```